# Multiindex notation for PDE's is the following statement correct?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

I am using Evan's second edition to learn about PDE's.

I particular there is a statement about linear PDE's

$$\sum_{|\alpha| \leq k} a_{\alpha}(x)D^\alpha u = f(x)$$

Where $\alpha$ is a vector of non-negative integers.

First, am I correct to state that the above sum is iterating over all possible permutations of vectors of order less than $k$? i.e. if $k$ is say 5 we would have $(5), (1, 4), (2, 3), (1,2,2) \cdots $ as possible values for $\alpha$ and we need to exhaust all of them to compute the sum, right?

Second question:

$u$ is the function, $Du$ is the gradient (a vector) $D^2u$ I think is the Jacobian (a matrix). Is it correct to say that $D^{n}$ is a tensor of dimension $n$ containing all possible permutations of partial derivatives that can be achieved with $n$ concatenations of the partial derivatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First question: the ordered multi-index is a list of orders for the individual partial operators, the sum of which adds up to $|\alpha|\leq k$. In symbols:
$$\partial_1^{\alpha_1}\circ ... \circ \partial_n^{\alpha_n} = D^{\alpha},$$
where $|\alpha|:=\alpha_1+...+\alpha_n$.
These amount to partitions (as opposed to permutations).
Second question: The Jacobian is a first order derivative matrix for multi-component functions of multiple variables (each row is a separate gradient), which is opposed to the Hessian (a second order derivative matrix). Considering higher order multi-indices suggests multi-dimensional arrays, similar to how tensors are stored in coordinates.
A subtlety is that the $D^k$ notation is actually the set of all $D^{\alpha}$ for $|\alpha|=k$. The gradient $\nabla$ and hessian $\nabla^2$ serve as convenient carriers of $D^1$ and $D^2$ for displaying PDEs in nice forms (such as dot product or determinant etc).